# Include both data and <Link> tag together in a table cell using reactjs and material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

im trying to include both data and a link tag together in 1 table cell but i can't get it to work.

[What i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/we3WH.png)

I've tried adding a "+" in between but it will show it as an object instead.

```
const rows = [
    createData("Created", "last week by @Jacob"),
    createData("Size", "572KB"),
    createData("Tags", "Mileage, Fare, Ticket"),
    createData("Dictionary", "2 files, 16 columns" + <Link>view</Link>)
];
```

[Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElBQI.png)

This is my code for the table. Can i know what should i change it to instead? Thanks!

```
<Table>
  <TableHead>
    <TableRow>
      <TableCell className={classes.cell}>About this dataset</TableCell>
      <TableCell align="left" className={classes.cell}>
        <Link>Edit</Link>
      </TableCell>
    </TableRow>
  </TableHead>
  <TableBody>
    {rows.map((row) => (
      <TableRow key={row.name}>
        <TableCell align="left" className={classes.cell}>
          {row.x}
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell align="left" className={classes.cell}>
          {row.y}
        </TableCell>
      </TableRow>
    ))}
  </TableBody>
</Table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `createData` does, and I'm assuming it just returns an object with properties `name`, `x`, and `y`. Here's how you can get your desired result:

1. Make sure your file is a `.jsx` or `.tsx` file.
2. Pass the second argument of `createData` as

```
    <>
      {"2 files, 16 columns "}
      <Link>view</Link>
    </>
```

Working Codesandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-brahmagupta-qwnr4?file=/src/App.tsx).